# Why does casting a string pointer to a void pointer and back cause the string data to dissappear? (Opencv)

Tags: string, pointers, opencv, void

I'm trying to create a function that initializes all my mouse handlers for every OpenCV window in one place.  The code works in the main loop, but not inside my function (Yes, I am passing by reference).
The problem seems to stem from passing a pointer to the string - when it comes out the other side it won't successfully dereference (*).  What gives?

Here's a minimalist example of what I'm talking about (It sets the mouse handlers for two identical windows - one window works, the other window doesnt):

```
// mouse problem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>  //for cout, cin

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){ 

    string windowname = *((string*)param);  //just recasting the void* we passed into the mousehandler to string
    if(windowname.empty()){
        cout << "ERROR.";
    }else{
        cout << "SUCCESS for window:" << windowname;
    }
    cout <<  "  param: "<< param << " windowname: "<< windowname << "\n";
}

void initializer(const string& name){
        namedWindow( name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        cout << " initializing mouse handler for " << name << " with string at address :" << &name << "\n";
        setMouseCallback(name, onMouse, (void*)&name);  //this line is exactly the same as the other setmousecallback line
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    string name; Mat src; VideoCapture cap(0);  cap >> src; // get a single frame from camera

    //this works just fine
    name = "frameA";
    namedWindow( name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cout << " initializing mouse handler for " << name << " with string at address :" << &name << "\n";
    setMouseCallback(name, onMouse, (void*)&name);

    //this fails even though it contains the same code and we pass by reference
    initializer("frameB");

    imshow("frameA",src);   imshow("frameB",src);  //display frame - mouseing over them triggers the OnMouse() event
    while(true){  //loop forever
        waitKey(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And [here is the result](http://screencast.com/t/E0CyoDJVm) after I mouseover each window once.

What really **KILLS** me is that, as you can see in the picture, the address of the string is successfully recognized!  And no errors on casting it to a string!  But when I de-reference it, it says its empty!
Yes, I did try to avoid using Void*.  Sadly, I cannot avoid the *void.  OpenCV requires a void* to be the last argument of any mousehandler function   :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the casts. You are keeping a pointer to a temporary `string` object, and are trying to dereference that pointer after the object has gone out of scope.

The following:

```
initializer("frameB");
```

is equivalent to:

```
initializer(std::string("frameB"));
```

In other words, a temporary is created, and the function takes and keeps the address of that temporary. Since the temporary disappears at the end of the statement, you are left with a dangling pointer.

Comment: So what is the address I am seeing for frameB referring to?

Comment: you're right.  :)  So simple.  Thank you!  So How can I pass in a string without having this problem?  I can't, can I?  I have to save each string in its own separate variable?  That kind of defeats the point of having it in a function.  :(